# How to set -backupTarget:\\?\Volume{GUID} correctly?

Tags: batch-file, backup, windows-server-2016

I want to create full system backup on my win server 2016 and save it to an external SSD.

I've a batch script that does this by:

1. enable and add scheduled backup
2. start backup

My problem is that when I enter the volume GUID as my `backupTarget`, the script fails and I get this error:

> ERROR - The specified backup location could not be found or is not a supported backup storage location`.

Code:

```
REM target and source are read from config file. I'll only add lines i have problem with here.
REM target={xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
REM source=c:

wbadmin enable backup ^-addTarget:"%target%" -schedule:21:00 -include:c: -vssFull -quiet

wbadmin start backup ^-backupTarget:"\\?\Volume%target%" -include:"%source%" -vssFull -systemState -quiet
```

When running directly in cmd I remove the `^`:

```
wbadmin enable backup -addTarget:"%target%" -schedule:21:00 -include:c: -vssFull -quiet

wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:"\\?\Volume%target%" -include:"%source%" -vssFull -systemState -quiet
```

Expected result should be that it manages to create the backup without failing, as it does if I run commands directly in `cmd.exe`.

I have tried the same line in `cmd.exe` and it works, but running it from within the script fails. Why is that?

Do I need to add some escape characters of some sort like the `^` that was needed for `-backupTarget` to be read correctly?

Appreciate all help I can get!

Comment: i see that the double backslashes in the beginning of the quote were changed to single in "\\?\Volume%target%" when i copied the text here

Comment: It should be `\\?\Volume\%target%` not `\\?\Volume%target%`! Also there's no reason at all to escape the `-` with a caret, it is not a poison character.

Comment: Thank you for answering and for editing my question before.I've tried your suggestion but still same error message. About the ^, i know it's weird but found a tip when googling that that was needed when typing -backupTarget in script, and when i entered it my script worked (on that occassion i used f: and not guid)

Comment: I really do not care what your Google search found, the standard characters used for providing arguments to command line processes are `/` and `-`, I simply do not accept that a built-in Windows command would need to have this non poisonous standard argument character escaped. Are you positive that the GUID you are using is 100% correct?

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of entering the drive GUID instead of the volume GUID.
With mountvol.exe I could see the correct GUID and then it worked.

wbAdmin doesn't like if you mount a volume to the system drive C:
So take care to mount it somewhere else, if you want to backup C.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Solution is use '\?\Volume{b51acf0e-8586-46a7-9bb5-d5ec83ba4936}'

'' character

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).